# Format string date "Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)" to "YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, format

How can I convert string "Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)" into 2015-03-25, new to Angular and javascript. Is there any function to make this convert?

Comment: [Use the `date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this worked for me

Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)

```
var date = new Date('Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)');
console.log(date);
var formatedDate = (date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());
console.log('Formated date' + formatedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var dt = new.Date(myDate);
var year = dt.getUTCFullYear();
var month = dt.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dt.getUTCDate();
var myNewdate= year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
var longDate = Date.parse('Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)');
var date = new Date(longDate);
alert(date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tq8jjw72/)